# How to combine two projects with similar structures using git

Tags: git

I have a question on how to combine two projects with a initial base using git

As a backstory, I am working with another developer, who has shared with me a project file, but has not committed anything to git. I take this project file and create a git repository.

The other developer does not clone the git repo, but still works on this project on his own local machine. At the same time, I am also working on the same project, but pushing changes to the git repository.

Now, we need to merge our work, but I am not sure how to do this using git. How would we go around merging our work using git? **The other developer can clone a copy of my repo, but how would he overlay his work onto mine?** There is the option to manually input code, but I feel that this would be very tedious and there is the possibility of missing something.

Is there a way to push his files onto the repo -> adding new files and not overriding the ones I currently have? Sorry if this is a simple question but I am not too well versed with Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new branch from your code branch (after committing your own changes). `git checkout -b <his_branch>`

On this new branch, copy the whole project of the other developer to replace your own project.

Then commit the changes on this branch.

Then checkout on your original branch `git checkout <your_branch>`

Finally, merge his branch on your local repo `git merge <his_branch>`
(resolve conflicts if any, here is an help for this purpose if you need: https://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts)